# Testing if user input is between 1-100 not working?

Tags: c#

I am debugging a "Guess the Number" program between 1-100. The first user creates a secretNumber and the second user guesses the number.

I'm trying to check if the second user input is a number between 1-100, but it still accepts negative numbers for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

Please note I am very new to coding, so I'm not well-versed with the jargon yet. In my class, we have just learned while loops and relational operators and if/else statements, so I am only allowed to use those.

The (`secretNumber == 0`) is to make sure `int.TryParse()` doesn't return 0 if the user typed in letters instead of numbers.

if statement checking:

```
( secretNumber >= 1 && secretNumber <= 100 )
```

and also

```
( secretNumber >= 1 || secretNumber <= 100 )
```

This is my code:

```
//Create a number variable to hold the whole number
int secretNumber;

//Validate that the number is a whole number AND between 1 and 100
if ( int.TryParse(secretNumberString, out secretNumber)
  || ( secretNumber >= 1 && secretNumber <= 100 )
  || secretNumber == 0 )
{

  // Tell the user the problem
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, please only type in whole numbers and it must be between 1 and 100!");

  // Re-ask the question
  Console.WriteLine("What is your secret number?");

  // Re-catch the response in the same variable
  secretNumberString = Console.ReadLine();

  // Re-assign the new input
  int.TryParse(secretNumberString, out secretNumber);

}
```

The if statement should run if the user inputs a negative value.

It runs if the user types a value above 100, but it doesn't run if the value is below 100. Otherwise, it shouldn't run if the number is correctly between 1-100.

Comment: Also, I have already tried to message my teacher for help, but I guess they are asleep. I'm frustrated because I feel like the answer to this is really simple and I am still getting it wrong after an hour of messing around with it...

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(secretNumberString, out secretNumber) ||` means if the user inputted an actual number OR ... You want AND

Comment: Any reason you are not using a NumericUpDown to obviate the entire problem?

Comment: @NoneoftheAbove I could only use things I learned in my class, and we had only learned booleans, relational operators, and if statements. ^^" I don't know yet what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read the documentation for [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) — it returns `true` *if* the string was successfully parsed as an integer and `false` otherwise. Your test, `int.TryParse( secretNumberString, out secretNumber ) || ( secretNumber >= 1 && secretNumber <= 100 ) || secretNumber == 0 )` will only ever test the value of `secretNumber` if the parse failed (at which point its value will be `0`).

This might get you started:

```
static int GetAnswer( string prompt, int min , int max )
{
  if (min > max) throw new ArgumentException("min must be less than or equal to max");
  int    value   ;
  bool   valid = false ;

  do
  {
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    string answer  = Console.ReadLine().Trim() ;

    valid =  int.TryParse(answer, out value)
          && value >= min
          && value <= max
          ;

    if (!valid)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, please only type in whole numbers in the range {min}-{max}.");
    }

  } while (!valid );

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out it was indeed a logic error. :) I managed to figure it out and turn my assignment in on time.

Answer (score 2):

The statement must be true if the input is either non-numeric or outside 1~100 range. Is that correct?

```cs
//if string is NOT integral (notice the !)   Or less than 1      Or bigger than 100
if (!int.TryParse(str, out int secretNumber) || secretNumber < 1 || secretNumber > 100)
```

Also, the user could still input non-integral, out-of-range number at the second attempt as it is not validated. Ideally, I believe it's better to put the validation logic as a loop variable:

```cs
string input;
int secretNumber;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input an integer between 1 and 100, inclusive.");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!int.TryParse(input, out secretNumber) || secretNumber < 1 || secretNumber > 100);
```

Comment: I really wish I could add a comment to other's answer... @TheGeneral The loop will never break as `str` does not change within the loop.

Comment: In case you're wondering do ... while () loops: It's equivalent of normal while loop except the condition is tested after the loop, meaning the code within the block will execute at least once. Also called Post-test loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `||` (or), this is just a simple Boolean Algebra (Propositional Logic) mistake, it needs to be `&&` (and)

However, a similar neater pattern is a condensed validation loop

```
var num = 0;

Console.WriteLine("What is your secret number between 1 and 100 inclusively?");
var str = Console.ReadLine();

// while its not a number, "or" the number is less or equal to 0 "or" greater than 100
// annoy them with a message 
while (!int.TryParse(str, out num ) || num  <= 0 || num  > 100)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Omg you had one job, a number between 1 and 100 inclusively... Try again");
   str= Console.ReadLine()
}

Console.WriteLine($"You won, your number is {num } ");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It turns out it was indeed a logic error. We hadn't yet learned loops at the time though, only if statements.